# Cannot inline buttons inside 3 divs with the same classes

Tags: html, css, inline

I have 3 divs with same classes like this:

```
<main>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/StormTrooper.png" alt="" />
            <h3>Return of the Jedi</h3>
            <p>E P I S O D E 6</p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Watch Now</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/R2D2.png" alt="" />
            <h3>The Force Awakens</h3>
            <p>E P I S O D E 7</p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Watch Now</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/Falkon.png" alt="" />
            <h3>The Last Jedi</h3>
            <p>E P I S O D E 8</p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Watch Now</button>
        </div>
    </main>
```

So the current output is :
[image]

The problem is that the elements inside the divs aren't ordered inline and dunno why. Here's my CSS:

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato";
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

main {
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    background: #729fcf;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.item {
    background: #f0ebff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box; float: left;

}

.item img {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline;
}

.item h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.item p {
    margin: 35px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.item button {
    background: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #6076cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QxOA.jpg
```

Long story short, the expected output is the following picture:
[image]
A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put the same size image in all three divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the `height` of `.item img` and `.item h3` as image could be of different height and text could be of different length.

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato";
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

main {
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    background: #729fcf;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.item {
    background: #f0ebff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box; float: left;

}

.item img {
    width: 100px;
    height:50px;
    display: inline;
}

.item h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 15px 0;
    height:50px;
}

.item p {
    margin: 35px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.item button {
    background: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #6076cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QxOA.jpg
```

```html
<main>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/StormTrooper.png" alt="" />
            <h3>Return of the Jedi</h3>
            <p>E P I S O D E 6</p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Watch Now</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/R2D2.png" alt="" />
            <h3>The Force Awakens</h3>
            <p>E P I S O D E 7</p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Watch Now</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/Falkon.png" alt="" />
            <h3>The Last Jedi</h3>
            <p>E P I S O D E 8</p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Watch Now</button>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

apply height to image accordingly it will solve the problem

```
.item img {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your image size is messing up your markup and also the margin on heading and paragraph tag, i altered some CSS in the code you provided, check it out, might be helpful

**HTML**

```
<main>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/StormTrooper.png" alt="" />
            <h3>Return of the Jedi</h3>
            <p>E P I S O D E 6</p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Watch Now</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/R2D2.png" alt="" />
            <h3>The Force Awakens</h3>
            <p>E P I S O D E 7</p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Watch Now</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/Falkon.png" alt="" />
            <h3>The Last Jedi</h3>
            <p>E P I S O D E 8</p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Watch Now</button>
        </div>
    </main>
```

**CSS**

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato";
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

main {
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    background: #729fcf;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.item {
    background: #f0ebff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box; float: left;

}

.item img {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline;
    height: 120px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.item h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.item p {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.item button {
    background: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #6076cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 35px;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1boqp50u/)

Answer (score 1):

add to the .item position:relative;
and than you can do this:

```
.item button {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    background: 0;
    border: 3px solid #6076cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

This will make the buttons be 10px from the bottom of .item

Answer (score 0):

I have added images of different sizes with some changes in your CSS. The buttons will remain inline whatever the image sizes are. Test it by resizing the screen and with longer headings as well. Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ammarhasan94/cg8w41zy/).

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato";
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

main {
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    background: #729fcf;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.item {
    background: #f0ebff;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box; float: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.item img {
    margin: auto 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
}

.item h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.item p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.seobook.com/images/smallfish.jpg" alt="" />
            <h3>Return of the Jedi</h3>
            <p>E P I S O D E 6 </p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Watch Now</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://png.icons8.com/material/1600/00897B/sailing-ship-small" alt="" />
            <h3>The Force Awakens</h3>
            <p>E P I S O D E 72345</p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Watch Now</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://en.opensuse.org/images/4/49/Amarok-logo-small.png" alt="" />
            <h3>The Last Jedi</h3>
            <p>E P I S O D E 8</p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Watch Now</button>
        </div>
    </main>
```